# SSIS Query Tables In Memory

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I've created an ETL which extracts data from our warehouse and puts this data into a flat file to be run into another warehouse. The ETL stages the data and pushes it into three tables. The volume of the data is quite large. The table sizes are roughly 8000 records in the first table, 150 000 records in the second table and 350 000 records in the third table.

The relationships of the tables, we will call them table 1, table 2 and table 3, are that references to table 2 and table 3 are made in table 1, where there is a one to many relationship between table 1 and table 2 and table 1 and table 3.

The layout of the flat file has to be as follows

**Table 1 Record 1**

Table 2 Record 1

Table 2 Record 2

Table 3 Record 1

Table 3 Record 2

**Table 1 Record 2**

Table 2 Record 3

Table 2 Record 4

Table 3 Record 3

Table 3 Record 4

I'm not sure how to do this in integration services without hitting the database 24000 times (Using a foreach loop starting with table 1, and then retrieving the values referenced in tables 2 and table 3 and writing these values to the flat file). What I almost need is a record set that I can query and store the data of tables 1, 2 and 3 in memory and query that. Could anyone point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: a merge join with a sort operation wont work?

Comment: From what I understand you can simply stage the flat files and run a single `UPDATE` over them afterwards.